# How to clone a JS object?

Tags: javascript

Right now to make a new object out of an existing object I stringify it, then parse it into a new variable.
Is there a better way?

eg:

```
let newObject = JSON.parse(  JSON.stringify(originalObject)  )
```

Comment: `Object.assign(target, [object,...])`

Comment: Do you want a "deep" copy of nested objects/arrays? Note that the way you've shown assumes the object can be stringified, which not all can so it could result in an error.

Comment: Note, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` approach will ignore function